# CCLayerGradient tint to

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

How can I use `CCTintTo` with `CCLayerGradient`? When I use default `CCTintTo` action on gradient layer only one color changing, but another color still the same. How can I change them all together?

Any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this:

 CCObject* child;
 CCARRAY_FOREACH(layer->getChildren(), child)
 {
    CCSprite* allSpriteChild = (CCSprite*) child;
    allSpriteChild->setColor(layer->getColor());

 }
```